# Lightweight process/daemon monitor? (ie. monitor and restart a single process)

Tags: monitoring, daemon, lightweight

Can anybody recommend a lightweight process/daemon monitor?

I'm running a user-land service process and I just need something to monitor and restart it when it crashes.  The system is running embedded linux so systemd isn't installed, etc.

I'm just looking for a single-binary monitor that can run like this:

/usr/bin/monitor my_process --restart=3

(ie. restart up to 3 times, or whatever other command-line options, etc)

Comment: process or daemon? if `my_process` can be run in *foreground*, and can be told to not try daemonize itself, simply `for i in 1 2 3; do my_process; done` will do ;-) But there are lightweight alternatives to systemd, e.g. OpenWRT's [procd](https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/procd)